# OpenGL forward-compatible context creation on Windows

Tags: c++

Is this the proper method for creating an OpenGL 3.3+ forward-compatible context?

```
// Create window
WNDCLASSEX wc;
ZeroMemory( &wc, sizeof( wc ) );
wc.cbSize = sizeof( wc );
wc.lpfnWndProc = _eventHandler;
wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle( NULL );
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
wc.hCursor  = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
wc.lpszClassName = "OpenGL 3.3";
if ( !RegisterClassEx( &wc ) ) Error( "Failed to register window class!" );
if ( !( _window = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "OpenGL 3.3", "OpenGL 3.3", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle( NULL ), NULL ) ) )
    Error( "Failed to create the window!" );
if ( !( _hdc = GetDC( _window ) ) ) Error( "Failed to retrieve device context!" );

// Choose pixel format
int pixelFormat;
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
ZeroMemory( &pfd, sizeof( pfd ) );
pfd.nSize = sizeof( pfd );
pfd.nVersion = 1; 
pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW;  
pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA; 
pfd.cColorBits = 32;
pfd.cDepthBits = 32; 
pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
if ( !( pixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat( _hdc, &pfd ) ) ) Error( "Failed to find suitable pixel format!" );
if ( !SetPixelFormat( _hdc, pixelFormat, &pfd ) ) Error( "Failed to set pixel format!" );

// Create temporary context and make sure we have support
HGLRC tempContext = wglCreateContext( _hdc );
if ( !tempContext ) Error( "Failed to create temporary context!" );
if ( !wglMakeCurrent( _hdc, tempContext ) ) Error( "Failed to activate temporary context!" );

int major, minor; glGetIntegerv( GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &major ); glGetIntegerv( GL_MINOR_VERSION, &minor );
if ( major < 3 || minor < 2 ) Error( "OpenGL 3.2 is not supported!" );

// Create forward compatible context
int attribs[] =
{
    WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, major,
    WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, minor, 
    WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
    WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
    0
};
PFNWGLCREATEBUFFERREGIONARBPROC wglCreateContextAttribsARB = (PFNWGLCREATEBUFFERREGIONARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress( "wglCreateContextAttribsARB" );
if ( !wglCreateContextAttribsARB ) Error( "Failed to find pointer to wglCreateContextAttribsARB function!" );
if ( !( _context = wglCreateContextAttribsARB( _hdc, 0, (UINT)attribs ) ) ) Error( "Failed to create forward compatible context!" );

// Remove temporary context and activate forward compatible context
wglMakeCurrent( NULL, NULL );
wglDeleteContext( tempContext );
if ( !wglMakeCurrent( _hdc, (HGLRC)_context ) ) Error( "Failed to activate forward compatible context!" );

// Show window
ShowWindow( _window, SW_SHOW );
UpdateWindow( _window );
```

It seems to work (gives GL_INVALID_OPERATION when using glBegin), but I just want to make sure this is the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *looks* right to me. I am a bit tired right now and usually use [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/).

You might be interested in [this page on the OpenGL wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial%3a_OpenGL_3.1_The_First_Triangle_%28C%2B%2B/Win%29) describing setting up the context after 3.1 which is essentially the same work.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a core profile (WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB) which means that all deprecated functionality will be unavailable. glBegin/glEnd was deprecated in OpenGL 3. The modern way to go is to use vertex buffer objects (VBOs) instead.

You can create a compability context to get access to the old fixed function API (including glBegin/glEnd).

For more information, see http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts

Comment: Yes, I tried calling glBegin to test the deprecation mechanism.

Comment: In 3.1 even core profiles contain and allow the deprecated stuff. See the wiki link above. For 3.3, yes, the core flag should do.